# Error testing PayPal Smart Buttons implementaion with REST API and triggering INSTRUMENT_DECLINED

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using PayPal's smart buttons with the [REST checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/) and using the server side to call the API.

I'm trying to work out how to handle [funding failures](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/) correctly.

I have no issues inserting the code, however I can't seem to get it to go into the correct section in the JS when there is a funding failure.

I was able to generate a mock `INSTRUMENT_DECLINED` error by simulating a negative response by passing the [correct mock headers](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/request-headers/) and error code; this was sent via the server side in the capture script.

**Here is my JS code for reference:**

```
paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        size: 'responsive',
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    createOrder: function() {

        // Make sure payment status alert is hidden first up...
        jQuery('.payment-status').hide();

        return fetch(blm_custom_vars.wp_home + 'classes/paypal/paypal-create-order.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data.result.id;
        });

    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch(blm_custom_vars.wp_home + 'classes/paypal/paypal-capture-order.php?order_id=' + data.orderID, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID: data.id
            })
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(orderData) {

            console.log(orderData);

            var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

            if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                console.log('Hi!');
                // return actions.restart();
            }

            if (errorDetail) {
                // Error here
            }

            alert('Transaction funds captured from ' + orderData.payer.name.given_name);

        })
    },
    onError: function (err) {
       // Error display here
    },
}).render('.purchase-modal');
```

Now, as you can see there is a check in there for `INSTRUMENT_DECLINED`; however when generating the mock error it never went in that section of the JS, it ended up in the `onError` section just like all other errors.

I then tried to generate one without mocking it by going to the payment screen so it could use the balance and then going back to my sandbox account and reducing the balance so they didn't have enough - however this had the same effect, straight into the `onError` section.

The only time I can ever seem to get it to go into the section above the `onError` is when the payment is *successful*.

I would like to test this out to see if it is working to make sure I have the code right as I have seen varying examples of what the correct code is to check that, from:

```
var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
    return actions.restart();
}
```

to...

```
if (orderData.error === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
    return actions.restart();
}
```

to...

```
if (orderData.details[0].issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
    return actions.restart(); 
}
```

Which looks like it is based off the first one.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I correctly simulate a `INSTRUMENT_DECLINED` error so that it ends up in the correct section in my JS code?

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen varying examples of what the correct code is to check that,

The "correct" code depends on what *your server* is sending back in its own response to the fetch request.  If you are simply sending back what the v2/checkout/orders API returns to a capture response (highly recommended for simplicity), then the code at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server is correct, and shows how to handle all 3 cases based on that format.

As far as how to trigger an INSTURMENT_DECLINED response, your capture call would have to include a mock header in the API request. A simpler way to trigger the same is to set the shipping address line 1 during checkout to: "`CCREJECT-REFUSED`" (mentioned in [old documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-fundingfailure10486/#test-a-sale-or-authorization-integration) from before the REST API existed)

Comment: Thanks. I have confirmed this does indeed return a `INSTURMENT_DECLINED`, however it still ends up in the `onError` section of the JS block and not in the section above it as expected.

Comment: You need to do something that returns in that section above (even just a "return;" after your `console.log()`), otherwise it will continue on in the function and reach the success portion that attempts to read the payer name, which will error out and trigger the catch-all `onError` since your JavaScript tried to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: That block isn't quite finished, but noted I will use a return; however the point is it's not even _entering_ that section unless it's successful (I'm getting no console log), that's what I'm trying to get working before I clean up and finish the rest of the block.

Comment: Study your console then, because I don't know what else would be causing it to enter onError before going into that block. Though, the block will be skipped over if your server's `orderData` response is not as expected.